# Creating an empty signature field in .pdf file using itextsharp library

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, digital-signature, vb.net-2010

This code should create a pdf file that contains an empty signature field:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Public Sub createPdfFileWithAnEmptySignatureField()
    Dim strOutputFilePath As String = "C:\Temp\File_ready_for_signing.pdf"
    Dim strFieldName = "myEmptySignatureField"
    Dim document As Document = New Document
    Dim writer As PdfWriter
    writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(strOutputFilePath, FileMode.Append))
    document.Open()
    document.Add(New Paragraph("This text element is successfully added, but the empty signature field is missing from this document, for some reason..."))
    Dim field As PdfFormField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer)
    field.SetWidget(New Rectangle(222, 222, 222, 222), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE)
    field.Name = strFieldName
    field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT
    field.SetPage()
    Dim tp As PdfAppearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(writer, 1222, 1222)
    tp.Rectangle(0.5!, 0.5!, 71.5!, 47.5!)
    tp.Stroke()
    field.SetAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp)
    writer.AddAnnotation(field)
    document.Close()
End Sub
```

It creates a pdf file with a text but the empty signature field is missing.

This is how an empty signature field should look.
[image: This is how an empty signature field would look.]

I found some similar questions:
[iTextsharp - Create Empty Signature Field -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626782/itextsharp-create-empty-signature-field)
[how can you create a signature field for a PDF template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202555/how-can-you-create-a-signature-field-for-a-pdf-template/13203165#13203165), but they don't fully answer my question.

**Edit:**
mkl solved it. Here's the final version:

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.IO

Public Sub createPdfFileWithAnEmptySignatureField()
     Dim strOutputFilePath As String = "C:\Temp\File_ready_for_signing.pdf"
    Dim strFieldName as String = "myEmptySignatureField"
    Dim document As Document = New Document
    Dim writer As PdfWriter
    writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(strOutputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
    document.Open()
    document.Add(New Paragraph("The following is an empty signature field:"))
    Dim field As PdfFormField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(writer)
    field.SetWidget(New Rectangle(50, 740, 120, 780), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE)
    field.FieldName = strFieldName
    writer.AddAnnotation(field)
    document.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code:

1. **Your signature field is 0×0 in size**, i.e. it is invisible.

   You define the signature field location and size here:

   ```
   field.SetWidget(New Rectangle(222, 222, 222, 222), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE)
   ```

   The `Rectangle` constructor is declared as

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Constructs a Rectangle-object.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="llx">lower left x</param>
   /// <param name="lly">lower left y</param>
   /// <param name="urx">upper right x</param>
   /// <param name="ury">upper right y</param>
   public Rectangle(float llx, float lly, float urx, float ury)
   ```

   Thus, you use the same coordinates for the lower left and the upper right corner. So your signature field has a 0×0 size and, therefore, is invisible.

   Assuming you thought the latter two parameters were width 222 and height 222, you should have used

   ```
   field.SetWidget(New Rectangle(222, 222, 444, 444), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE)
   ```
2. **Your signature field has no field name**. Yes, you set the `Name` property:

   ```
   field.Name = strFieldName
   ```

   but this only sets the name of the widget *annotation*. For a form field to work properly, though, the *form field* itself needs a name while the annotation name is optional:

   ```
   field.FieldName = strFieldName
   ```
3. **You create the PDF file in `Append` file mode**:

   ```
   writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(strOutputFilePath, FileMode.Append))
   ```

   This generally is a bad idea as a concatenation of PDFs is no valid PDF document anymore. You should use the `Create` file mode instead:

   ```
   writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(strOutputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
   ```

With these changes applied you get this:

[image: screenshot]

By the way, probably another error is your choice of appearance size:

```
Dim tp As PdfAppearance = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(writer, 1222, 1222)
```

In particular as you merely draw a tiny rectangle on it:

```
tp.Rectangle(0.5!, 0.5!, 71.5!, 47.5!)
```

Unless this indeed is desired, you'll have to use better matching sizes.